# Fortran - цикл do while

Tags: fortran, циклы

Здравствуйте. В основной программе в этом примерном блоке не происходит перезаписывания ini, из-за этого вычисляется значение om_, например равное 0.4, и всё. Дальше программа оставляет исходный массив ini. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть ошибка?

```
 ini = reshape(ini_st, forma)
 fin = reshape(fin_st, forma)
  do 652 while (om_ > 0.01)
   do i = 1, 3
   do k = 1, m
    vector (i,k) = fin(i,k)-ini(i,k)
   end do
   end do
...................................................
  om_ = sqrt(om(1)**2 + om(2)**2 + om(3)**2) !om зависят от ini
   do i = 1, 3
   do j= 1, m
  ini(i,j) = cos(om_)*ini(i,j) 
   end do
   end do
  652 continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[[[@Danaida](/users/23929/danaida)](/users/23929/danaida)](/users/23929/danaida)](/users/23929/danaida), по крайней мере в приведенном коде массив `om` не меняется (хотя в комментарии указано, что зависит от `ini`), поэтому переменная `om_` на всех итерациях остается постоянной.

**Обновление**

[[[[@Danaida](/users/23929/danaida)](/users/23929/danaida)](/users/23929/danaida)](/users/23929/danaida), видимо, код (его много, и Вы его тут не написали), который должен менять `om` в соответствии с текущим состоянием `ini`, не работает должным образом.

Больше тут предположить нечего.

Comment: Массив om находится из ini, здесь просто не написано, поскольку много шагов. Я предполагаю, что если перезапишется ini, то автоматически и om, а соответственно и om_, будут меняться.

Comment: @avp: Вот это да, вы ещё и спец по Фортрану!

Comment: @VladD, все швейные машинки похожи друг на друга. :)

Answer (score 2):

Когда я изучал фортран, а это было во времена Сулеймана ибн Давида (мир с ними обоими!), то согласно стандарту, первые буквы имен переменных определяли их тип.  
Так, переменные, начинающиеся на i, j, k, l, m, n, o - считались целоисчесленными.    
Попробуйте переменную om заменить на am, или bm, иначе говоря, первая буква не должна быть из перечня выше - тогда интерпретатор Фортран будет обрабатывать вашу переменную как вещественное число, а не целое.  
Хвала Аллаху и его верному почитателю [Аль-Хорезми](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B8)!

Comment: Хорошее предположение 

(правда, по словам автора `om_` постоянно равно **0.4**).

Comment: Автор ни слова не сказал ни о версии фортрана, ни о среде его применения, - поэтому я позволил себе сказку Шахеризады, да простит меня в этом благородное собрание. ;)

Comment: @deivan, все правильно

(только `o` -- это уже перебор).

Comment: Да, про О я переборщил, спасибо за намек:   http://www.chem.ox.ac.uk/fortran/variables.html

Comment: Всем спасибо за внимание к вопросу и помощь, пишу в 90-м фортране в среде Geany. До цикла задала явно значение om_ и вроде как стало считать.